# How to change values in dataframe replace floating point numbers with integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

lets say i have a dataframe

```
A   B     C 
I   8.0   9.0
II  7.0   4.0
X   2.0   3.0
```

how do i change it to

```
A   B    C 
I   8    9
II  7    4
X   2    3
```

Comment: `df[['B', 'C']] = df[['B', 'C']].astype('int')`

Answer (score 2):

You must make sure that your columns don't have any `NaN` values. By default, a numeric column containing `NaN` values will have its non-null numeric values stored as floats, and there is no way to convert this to `int` as is (without removing the missing values). Assuming you have no missing values:

```
df[['B', 'C']] = df[['B','C']].astype('int')
```

If you have `NaN` values:

```
df[['B', 'C']] = df[['B','C']].dropna().astype('int')
```

Comment: The latter is not the best approach actually .. you'll lose data

Comment: How about applymap(int)